# How do I write SQL to Substring data in this table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's the data in 1 field in the database:

```
{"image": null, "endDate": "2016-08-26", 
"features": {"Attendee List": true, "Event Feedback": true, "Session Feedback": true}, 
"startDate": "2016-08-25", 
"description": null, "selectedTimeZone": "America/Chicago", "popularityThreshold": 45, "twentyFourHourClockOn": false}
```

I need to extract the values for "endDate" and the "startDate" something like this:

```
Select t.somefield, t.startdate(substring()), t.enddate(substring)) from tablename
```

**Something like this:**

value, 2016-08-25, 2016-08-26

The database is PostgreSQL.
[here's a sample select query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkzJy.png)

Need some assistance writing the substring (it's been a while), and I'm only writing the query for reporting needs.

Comment: What DB server do you use? MySql? PostgreSql? MS Sql? Oracle? Another?

Comment: Does your DBMS support JSON functions (e.g. like Postgres?)

Comment: JSON parsing in SQL is not for the faint-hearted.

Comment: Added some follow ups. Thx in advance.

Comment: @MattKhoury unfamiliar with `Postgres` and assuming my answer won't help much in this context, so deleting it. Best of luck!

Comment: Well, given you won't have the ability to search/sort this (given substringing), why not go back to whatever put the data _in_ in this format?  Rather, why not just parse it as a JSON object (if that's what it is), and deal with it that way, rather than a somewhat problematic substring.  I mean, what happens if the fields happen to show up somewhere else in there (in `description` or something)?

Comment: Oh wait, yeah, if it's JSON, [tell Postgres to parse it for you](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html).  Don't substring it yourself (thanks @a_horse_with_no_name).

Comment: Thanks anyway @levelonehuman!

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Postgres' JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html):

```
select (content::json ->> 'startDate')::date as start_date,
       (content::json ->> 'endDate')::date as end_date, 
       e.some_column
from events e
```

Comment: Yes! Perfect! (Thank you!)